# Xcode 4.4 is hanging when writing large log strings to the console

Tags: ios, xcode

As of Xcode 4.4, debugging my app crashes the IDE if I am writing a lot of log messages to the console. In this particular project I am using RestKit, and when I turn RestKit logging on to RKLogLevelTrace and debug the app, Xcode will crash when I am fetching or sending large amounts of data to the web service (and consequently doing a lot of logging).

1. Are other people seeing this issue?
2. Is there any way to fix this problem, or just hope that Apple releases a bug fix for it?

**UPDATE** It looks to me like Apple fixed this issue as of Xcode 4.4.1 / 4.5 DP4.

Comment: I still see this issue with XCode 4.4.1. Turning off large amounts of logging make XCode work normally again.

Comment: Yes I still see the issue too, although I haven't gotten it to freeze Xcode entirely, merely show the BBOD for a while. Still not good though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. There's an open radar bug for this: [Xcode showing "beach ball" when logging a very long string trough NSLog](http://openradar.appspot.com/11972490). I think we have to wait for a bug fix release.

Comment: Thanks, I filed a radar for it.

Comment: Close this now that 4.5 is out?